# SimpleXMLElement from curl response - problem with @attributes

Tags: php, attributes, simplexml

XML code from response:

```
<hints label="luggage">20</hints>
<hints label="handluggage">5</hints>
<hints label="landing"></hints>
```

After this function with response:

```
$arrayResponse = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($response)), true);
```

I have this:

```
"hints" => [
    0 => "20",
    1 => "5",
    2 => [
        @attributes = [
            label => "landing"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Keys "luggage" and "handluggage" does not exists.

How to get the **KEYS** with values from XML?
Example:

```
[
  "luggage" => 20,
  "handluggage" => 5,
  "landing" => null
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution without using `json`:

```
$response = '<root><hints label="luggage">20</hints><hints label="handluggage">5</hints><hints label="landing"></hints></root>';
$a = [];
foreach (simplexml_load_string($response)->hints as $hint) {
    $value = (string)$hint;
    $a[(string)$hint['label']] = $value ?: null;
}
print_r($a);
```